# Switch website background video to image

Tags: video, mobile, background, youtube, switch-statement

My website uses a background video in the home section with the html layered on top of it using jQuery.mb.YTPlayer. Mobile devices won't play the link automatically (and never will, as I've learned). Because of the rest of the site's html being on top the video it's also impossible to press the play button.

I'd like the site to switch to an alternative. (a still image or maybe a simpler image sequence).
The address is http://kumquat.nl

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using framework (jQuery plugin in your case) for background video in website is good but that way we are restricted to some functionality only,  provided by the author of the framework and any addition to the code must tested ,so it does not give any unwanted result

I hope you have taken the jQuery.mb.YTPlayer plugin from the following website
Click [here](http://pupunzi.com/#mb.components/mb.YTPlayer/YTPlayer.html)!

**After some research i got this Github code which might answer your question Click [here](https://github.com/pupunzi/jquery.mb.YTPlayer/issues/34#event-154967389)!**

Not Satisfied !

Then you can try this, 
instead of using a jQuery Plugin 
you can use the *HTML5 Video Tag*

```
  <video autoplay loop poster="image url" id="bgvid">

       <source src="video url" type="video/mp4"> 

       <source src="video url" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>
  </video>
```

then target the it using *bgvid*

```
    <style type="text/css">

video#bgvid
 {

 position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
 min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
 width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
 background: url(image url) no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;

 }
```

image provided in the image url will be shown till the video loads on desktop and in mobile it will show the image instead of the video.

For more info Click [here](http://demosthenes.info/blog/777/Create-Fullscreen-HTML5-Page-Background-Video)!

To see the example Click [here](http://creative-form.paperplane.io/)!

Comment: Thanks Mohammad,I'm going to try this out and i'll get back to you. The background img mentioned in the Github linked worked.